# Differentiating $y=\exp(x+\exp(x+\exp(x+\exp(x+\cdots))))$ and writing derivatives of $\exp$ functions in terms of $y$ only

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function, implicit-differentiation

I want to differentiate $$y=\exp(x+\exp(x+\exp(x+\exp(x+\cdots)))).$$

Is the following substitution and differentiation appropriate?

\begin{align}
y&=\exp(x+\exp(x+\exp(x+\exp(x+\cdots))))\\
y&=\exp(x+y)\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\exp(x+y)\left(1+\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=y\left(1+\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{y}{1-y}\\
\end{align}

As well, I notice that I can write the derivative (and therefore any higher order derivative) in terms of $y$ only.  What is required of the $\exp$ function such that I will not be able to write the derivative in terms of $y$ only?  It does not seem like the reason is that the $x$ in the argument is just $x$ and not some function of $x$:  for example,
\begin{align}
y&=\exp x^2\qquad\quad\implies x=\log y-\log2\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=2x\exp x^2\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=2xy\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=2y\,(\log y-\log2)\\
\end{align}
and now the derivative is free of $x$.  Knowing when this is the case would be useful in constructing problems where we can find the slope of the tangent line given only a $y$ value.

Comment: Whenever you can write $x=f(y)$, you should be able to replace it if it happens to occur in the expression for $\frac{dy}{dx}$.